# problems installing firebase pods

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

When I attempted to install the pod after modifying and saving the profile file this is what I get (info from terminal window):

> Scotts-Mac:SDADishApp Scott$ pod install
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Generating Pods project
>
> Integrating client project
>
> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `SDADishApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
>
> Sending stats
>
> Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total
>
> pods installed.
>
> [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
>
> Scotts-Mac:SDADishApp Scott$

Could you please tell me what I did wrong? And how to correct it? There should be dependencies and pods installed.

Comment: It looks like your Podfile has no dependencies. Please post the contents of your Podfile.

Comment: profile contents are as follows: 
`platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'SDADishApp' do
  pods 'Firebase'
  Pods for SDADishApp

end`